# Optimizing a method that cross fills missing data

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have two tables of demographic data on employees of the same company from separate sources.  After applying identical formatting and sorting each table, some columns are blank because that source didn't export that data.

Both tables formatted looks like `uniqueID | ssn | ...` and are sorted by `uniqueID`.  Source A doesn't export the social-security numbers, so the `ssn` column for table A is blank.  Source B does export the social-security numbers.  I want to fill in the `ssn` column of table A using the data from table B and the `uniqueID` as the key.

Social Security number is also a unique ID for my purposes so there will never be an ssn paired with two uniqueID's or visa-versa.

Persons (`uniqueID | ssn`) can appear multiple times on the same table, and different amount of times across tables.  Some persons might be on one table and not the other.

My current solution in VBA is,

```
Function crossFillMissingDemos( tableA as Range, tableB as Range)
    Dim crntID As Variant: crntID = tableB.Cells(1,"A").Value
    For Each demoB In tableB.Rows
        If crntID <> demoB.Cells(1, "A").Value Then
            crntID = demoB.Cells(1, "A").Value
            For Each demoA In tableA.Rows
                If demoA.Cells(1, "A").Value = crntID Then
                    demoA.Cells(1,"B").Value = demoB.Cells(1,"B").Value   
                End If
            Next demoB
        End If
    Next demoB 
Exit Function
```

which gets slower as the table sizes increase because it has `tableB.personCount * tableA.RowCount` operations.

Is there more ways to optimize this function or better approach to it?

Comment: Where is crntID assigned a value??...........Why are you using a Function rather than a Sub??

Comment: Sounds like a nested `VLOOKUP` or some form of array-entered `INDEX` can actually do this.

Comment: Export your two tables to ACCESS; perform the join using SQL; and return the result to EXCEL.

Comment: Forgot to init crntID in the example.  I personally don't make functions Subs unless they take no args.  That way any sub can be a macro.  I'll try the rest after the holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your code.  On the second row, you use `demoB` as a predefined range while on the third row you use it as a For-Next loop variable.  Should `crntID = demoB.Cells(1,"A").Value` be inside the loop?

You state the two tables are sorted into the same sequence so I do not understand the use of nested For-Next loops.  All you need to do is step down the two tables matching and copying values.  This requires TableA.Rows.Count + TableB.Rows.Count steps; note: plus not times.   In my code I have taken the additional step of copying the range values to arrays which will make the code a little faster.  I have used Debug.Print to display addresses and array bounds because values may not be what you expect.

I created two worksheets (SheetA and SheetB) which match my understanding of the sort of tables you have:

[image: Sheet A before macro]

[image: Sheet B]

After the macro, worksheet SheetA looks like this:

[image: Sheet A after the macro]

My entire code is below.  It functions correctly with my test data but I have not exhaustedly tested it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CallCrossFillMissingDemos()

  Dim ColShtAMax As Long
  Dim ColShtBMax As Long
  Dim RngA As Range
  Dim RngB As Range
  Dim RowShtAMax As Long
  Dim RowShtBMax As Long

  With Worksheets("SheetA")
    ColShtAMax = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    RowShtAMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set RngA = Worksheets("SheetA").Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                                          .Cells(RowShtAMax, ColShtAMax))
  End With
  With Worksheets("SheetB")
    ColShtBMax = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    RowShtBMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set RngB = Worksheets("SheetB").Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                                          .Cells(RowShtBMax, ColShtBMax))
  End With

  Call crossFillMissingDemos(RngA, RngB)

End Sub
Function crossFillMissingDemos(ByVal tableA As Range, ByVal tableB As Range)

   Debug.Print "Table A is " & tableA.Worksheet.Name & ".Range(" & tableA.Address & ")"
   Debug.Print "Table B is " & tableB.Worksheet.Name & ".Range(" & tableB.Address & ")"

   Dim IdACrnt As String
   Dim IdBCrnt As String
   Dim RowACrnt As Long
   Dim RowBCrnt As Long
   Dim SSNCrnt As String
   Dim TableAValues As Variant
   Dim TableBValues As Variant

   ' Copy values from ranges to arrays
   TableAValues = tableA.Value
   TableBValues = tableB.Value

   Debug.Print "TableAValues(" & LBound(TableAValues, 1) & " To " & _
               UBound(TableAValues, 1) & ", " & LBound(TableAValues, 2) & _
               " To " & UBound(TableAValues, 2) & ")"
   Debug.Print "TableBValues(" & LBound(TableBValues, 1) & " To " & _
               UBound(TableBValues, 1) & ", " & LBound(TableBValues, 2) & _
               " To " & UBound(TableBValues, 2) & ")"
   ' Note: although the ranges start from row 2, the arrays start from 1.
   ' Whatever range you load to an array, the top left cell will be (1, 1)

   ' Initialise control variables
   RowACrnt = 1
   IdACrnt = TableAValues(RowACrnt, 1)
   RowBCrnt = 1
   IdBCrnt = TableBValues(RowBCrnt, 1)
   SSNCrnt = TableBValues(RowBCrnt, 2)

   ' Loop down arrays copying SSNs from array copy of TableB
   ' to array copy of TableA as appropriate
   Do While True
     If IdACrnt = IdBCrnt Then
       ' Rows are for same person.  Copy SSN to Table A
       TableAValues(RowACrnt, 2) = SSNCrnt
       RowACrnt = RowACrnt + 1
       If RowACrnt <= UBound(TableAValues, 1) Then
         IdACrnt = TableAValues(RowACrnt, 1)
       Else
         ' All rows in Table A have been processed
         Exit Do
       End If
     ElseIf IdACrnt < IdBCrnt Then
       ' IdACrnt is not present in TableB
       RowACrnt = RowACrnt + 1
       If RowACrnt <= UBound(TableAValues, 1) Then
         IdACrnt = TableAValues(RowACrnt, 1)
       Else
         ' All rows in Table A have been processed
         Exit Do
       End If
     Else
       ' IdACrnt > IdBCrnt
       ' If this person is present in TableB, they are further down table
       RowBCrnt = RowBCrnt + 1
       If RowBCrnt <= UBound(TableBValues, 1) Then
        SSNCrnt = TableBValues(RowBCrnt, 2)
         IdBCrnt = TableBValues(RowBCrnt, 1)
       Else
         ' All rows in Table B have been processed
         Exit Do
       End If
     End If
   Loop

   ' Copy Updated TableAValues back to range
   tableA.Value = TableAValues

End Function
```

Comment: I initially forgot to init `crntID` in the example and then improperly initialized it.  `demoA` should have been `tableA`.